# what is write() function in openerp framework?

Tags: odoo

I am beginner to openerp framwork
I want to know how to use write() and create() methods and what is its purpose?. I already read the docs from openerp but still I am not getting it.

Comment: Try using googling first before asking basic questions here...

Comment: I won't get into the argument of what defines "basic" but I dont think this is a trivial question.

Comment: I have asked this question in my initial time, even now I am feel stupid for this questio ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**create(cr, uid, values, context=None)**

Creates new record. This method is invoked every time click on the 'New' button and the you save trough the 'Save' button.

The parameters `cr` and `uid` are well known - the database cursor object and the ID of the user executing the action.

`values` is a dictionary containing the values to store in the new record. The dictionary elements are in the form `{'field_name': 'field_value',}`.

Let say you have a `Student(osv.osv)` model with `name`, `fac_id` and `fac_no` fields. You can create a new Student's record using the following call somewhere inside the `Student` class:

```
new_student_id = self.create(cr, uid, {'name': 'Joe Doe', 
                                       'fac_id': 15, 
                                       'fac_no': '161832'})
```

**write(cr, uid, ids, values, context=None)**

Similar to `create()` but updates existing record(s). Which records to update is defined by the `ids` parameter. If you want to update the `fac_id` field of students with ids 166 and 299 you can do it in the following way:

```
self.write(cr, uid, [166, 299], {'fac_id': 21})
```

Answer (score 1):

**Create:**
when ever user saves record in the OpenERP for particular model, that time the create method is being called by the ORM.

**Write:**
once the record is being created and then if the user modify & save the record that time the write method is being called.

This is the basic difference of create and write method.

Download the [OpenERP Developer Memento](https://www.odoo.com/files/memento/OpenERP_Technical_Memento_latest.pdf), It will help you a lot!